# Magento 2 : AdvancedSalesRule override validate method

Tags: overrides, magento2.2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I need to validate custom quote item details, So I am overriding module **AdvancedSalesRule** "**\Magento\AdvancedSalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product**" file. But Not getting quote item Id in model object. Below is code of override method.

```
/**
     * Validate Product Rule Condition
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validate(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model)
    {
        //@todo reimplement this method when is fixed MAGETWO-5713
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
        $product = $model->getProduct();
        if (!$product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($model->getProductId());
        }

        if ($model instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item) {
            echo $model->getItemId(); die; // Null
```

Comment: Can you please tell on what step you want to validate item detail and an example for it ?

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated the same override on a test server M 2.2.2 with following code.

```
<?php

  namespace Net\Demo\Model\Rule\Condition;

  class Product extends \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product {

    public function validate(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model)
    {
       //@todo reimplement this method when is fixed MAGETWO-5713
       /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
       $product = $model->getProduct();

      if (!$product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
        $product = $this->productRepository->getById($model->getProductId());
      }
      echo "<br>------".get_class($model)."---".$model->getItemId();
      $product->setQuoteItemQty($model->getQty())
              ->setQuoteItemPrice($model->getPrice()) // possible bug: need to use $model->getBasePrice()
              ->setQuoteItemRowTotal($model->getBaseRowTotal());
```

I am correctly getting the quote item id for the product as follows:

[image]

> $model->getItemId();

so you should check your installation or upgrade it, it should work

Regards

Sunil